# How to make uncooked onion digestable?

Tags: onions

I have a problem with uncooked, sliced onion making me and other people feel uncomfortable in the stomach, sometimes whole night. However, when I eat tacos out in restaurants that never happens. Is it due to the variety of onion or do they prepare them in a certain way?

Comment: Do the ones that don't give you trouble taste different, perhaps milder?

Comment: A few places I have worked have kept the prepped onions in water or brine to keep them from drying out until they're used. I know that definitely seemed to take a lot of the "heat" out...

Comment: The reason I asked is that if all you need to do is reduce the strength of the onion, that's already been asked and answered: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20263/how-do-i-tone-down-the-intensity-of-raw-onion

Comment: @Jefromi I don't know to be honest. I'll need to find them again and "study" them, but I'm not frequenting those places and don't know when is the next time I can taste onions there. I tried other commenter's advice and it seemed to help a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding salt and lemon should do it, or at least help a lot.

What you want to do is to chop them up and rub in a little salt and a splash of lemon juice (vinegar should work too). Obviously you don't want to add so much of either that you won't want to eat the onion.
Leave to sit in the fridge overnight and enjoy.

Comment: Just to add that there seems to be plenty of similar advice around on the internet, so it's good to try similar techniques and see what you like the best.

Answer (score -1):

Red onions are the best to use raw, and as I know a few people who get uncomfortable or upset stomachs when eating raw onion, even though others don't. I think it could be a particular allergy type thing. I'm not sure though so I will check that out. It could be good to store them in something though before serving (the onions not the people).