# How do I save my curry with too much of a raw onion smell?

Tags: onions, curry

I was cooking for a party and ground my raw onions, added to oil and then added meat. Now the curry is sweet and smells like raw onion. How do I save this curry so I can use it for the party?

Comment: At the very least, I'd try cooking it for a while.  I'm guessing that the grinding of the onions released too many sulfur compounds.  (the best solution to this is to cook the onions before disrupting the cell walls too much).  Acids might also help, but it's usually used as a soak before cooking.  See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20263/67 ;

Answer (score 1):

Don't grind the onion too fine. Just chop it fine.

Now if it is done add some oil and put it on low heat till it starts to taste better.

Answer (score -1):

The taste of the raw onion can be nullified by salt, vinegar, lemon, tomato, sugar depending upon the recipe you are making. All of them could never be used in the same recipe but i believe that at least you can use one of them. Depending upon the type of the onion, I am not so specific about the type. You can peel them, cut them in half and then put them in water with few drops of vinegar for a bit.

I usually prefer to cook onion first but in chillies we prefer raw right...?

I hope this helps....